# Is it less likely to get infected by a second virus while fighting first?

Tags: virus, infectious-diseases

By and large, when a person gets ill with eg. flu, it is sort of assumed at least by many people with no medical background in my vicinity, that the person won't get infected by another virus meantime. Now, this doesn't work for, eg, bacterial infections and similar (a bacterial pneumonia being common complication of flu).

But are there any other reasons why infection by multiple viruses at the same time might be less likely, except for the fact that an ill person is not likely to run around to get additional infections?

Comment: Who said you can't get multiple different virus infections concurrently?

Comment: An infection can often make you _more_ susceptible to a secondary infection, both viral and bacterial.